# Python sorting being undone when creating dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that I am converting to a list so I can sort it. The dictionary is a key/value pair. I convert it to the list, sort it, and then later convert it back to a dictionary. When I convert it back to a dictionary, it goes back to being unsorted. Can someone either help me sort it as a dictionary or how to keep my list from becoming unsorted when I convert it back to a dictionary?

```
# Unsorted dictionary passed in. Convert it to a list for sorting.
temp_list = [str(i) for i in unsorted_dictionary_passed_in]
temp_list.sort()

# Debug print to show list is actually sorted.
print (temp_list)

# After this function, the dictionary is no longer sorted.
final_dictionary = dict.fromkeys(temp_list, 'Value added to each key')
```

What am I doing wrong or need to do to keep it sorted when it becomes a dictionary?

Comment: A plain dictionary is not meant to keep order, it's meant to access its values fast using a given key. If you want a specialized dictionary that does just that, use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: `sorted_list = unsorted_list.sort()` Since `sort` returns `None`, this code won't work. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Also the way you use `fromkeys` will create a dictionary where the keys are the _key-value pairs_ and the "value" is the same string for all keys. I suspect you want to use a generator or some other mechanism

Comment: @enzo Dict is guaranteed to keep insertion order since Python 3.7. It de-facto does so already since CPython 3.6 and PyPy 2.7.

Comment: @DStanley, I do wanted the same "default" value to start with. The intent of the dictionary is to change the values based on an operation that happens later.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? This should work in all currently supported versions. (Well, in principle it should - the code is broken but in a different way.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am using version 3.4.4. One thing I just noticed (or realized) is that when recreating the dictionary (fromkeys), is that the order the keys are put in the dictionary are random...or look to be, which is why I'm running into this. I believe I need to recreate the dictionary by iterating through the list that I previously sorted and add each dictionary key/value one at at time.

Comment: Dictionaries have arbitrary order in Python 3.4 - you cannot have a sorted dictionary then. While you could fix that with Ordered Dict, you should really, really, really just update Python. Python 3.4 is *seriously* outdated and hasn't been supported in ages.

Comment: @Wannabe My point is that the keys in our new dictionary are not the same keys from the original dictionary - the keys are tuples (the key/value _pairs_ from the original). That seems odd but maybe that's what you want...

Comment: @DStanley, yes that what I want. At the point where I am ordering my keys, it does not matter. I pass the dictionary back to another function to evaluate and populate the values. Thanks, knowing that helped me figure it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
dic1 = {2:90, 1: 100, 8: 3, 5: 67, 3: 5}
dic2 = {}
for i in sorted(dic1):
    dic2[i]=dic1[i]
print(dic2)
```

Result:

```
{1: 100, 2: 90, 3: 5, 5: 67, 8: 3}
```

Comment: This won’t actually work if they are on Python 3.4.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yes, I found out. Unfortunately, this is at work and in an area where we do not get the liberty to upgrade very easy. Discussions in the comments helped out and this solution will hopefully help someone else.